# Insert into table from temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have the following table:

**Example**:

```
create table test
(
 col1 varchar(10),
 col2 varchar(20),
 col3 varchar(30)
);
```

Now I want to insert two values by variables and last one by #temp table.

**#Temp**:

```
create table #temp
(
  col3 varchar(30)
);
```

**#Temp**: Contains

```
col3
-----
A1
A2
A3
```

Insertion into test table:

```
Declare @col1 varchar(10) = 'A'
Declare @col1 varchar(20) = 'B'
Declare @sql varchar(max)

SET @SQL = N'insert into test values('+@col1+','+@col2+',........); 
EXEC(@SQL)
/* How to insert `@col3` from #temp to test table*/
```

**Expected Result**:

```
col1   col2   col3
------------------
A      B      A1
A      B      A2
A      B      A3
```

**Note**: The variables values must repeat until the #temp values inserted into table test.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT @col1, @col2, col3
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: What if I like to insert into test(col1,col3)? Not col2

Comment: Just specify the columns you want in the insert: `INSERT INTO test (col1, col3) SELECT @col1, col3 FROM #temp`

Comment: Great answer, simple and effective.