# How to insert into a table from temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I already have values in a temp table and I want to insert it into my table.

I follow this syntax

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC abc JOIN #Temp t ON abc.ID = t.ID)

insert into MyTable(Id,Name)
select values (t.ID, t.Name)
From t
```

I have just the name t as an alias I created in a condition before this insert.

Is this correct? Some people use @ etc. I am confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert into table from temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445247/insert-into-table-from-temporary-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
insert into MyTable(Id,Name)
select t.ID, t.Name
From #temp t
```

Always [read manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I always see that some people who use @, they use @ in first field and rest all just field name and in your query, you use t in last field and not in first field? Confused..

Comment: Everyone's answer is different here :( I am confused

Comment: @Deevinee You can't use alias defined elsewhere, Alias always work in one current instruction, so you need `insert into MyTable(Id,Name)
select ID, t.Name
From #temp t`

Comment: Thank you, and my question about t in Name and not in ID ?

Comment: @Deevinee You want ID from parameter? Like `insert into MyTable(Id,Name)
select @ID, t.Name
From #temp t
`

Comment: No, just confused why you didn't use t.ID? and just ID but in 2nd field you use t.Name and not just name...

Comment: @Deevinee If you have one table and no ambiguous name you can skip alias part.

Comment: Thank you :) I am leaving home. Its 9 PM. I came at 8 AM :( Damn !!! Haha somehow got two SPs down :) Thanks so much for your help, see you tomorrow :) Have a good day....

Answer (score 0):

You can check  this

```
insert into Table1(Id,Name) 
select ID,Name
From t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table_name(column_name1,column_name2,column_name3)
(select temp_table_col1_1,temp_table_col1_1,temp_table_col1_1 
 from temp_table_name
 <where condition if needed>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Name)
SELECT t.ID, t.Name FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC abc JOIN #Temp t ON abc.ID = t.ID)

    insert into MyTable(Id,Name) select t.ID, t.Name From #Temp t
```

Temp Table

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( Name VARCHAR(MAX) )
```

Global Temp Table

```
CREATE TABLE ##Temp1 ( Name VARCHAR(MAX) )
```

Table Variable

```
DECLARE @Temp1 TABLE( Name VARCHAR(MAX) )
```

In SQL Server, for temp table we used '#' and for table variable we used '@'. 
For more detailed information about temp table and table variable please look into [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into MyTable(Id,Name)
(select t,Name From t)
```